# D4 D5 C4 NF6 Continuation

Tags: positional-play, correspondence-chess

I'm a quiet and positional player rated in the 1400's and play exclusively online correspondence chess. I always play D4 with white as first move and usually C4 after that.

One opening I come into quite often is D4 D5 C4 NF6

After this what is the most solid play for white to get a strategic advantage for long term correspondence play?

Answer (score 1):

This opening **1.d4 d5 2.d4 Nf6** is known as the *Marshall Defense* of the Queen's Gambit Declined.  White can get an advantage with **3.cxd5** resulting in an advantage, such as **3...Nxd5 4.Nf3 Bf5 5.Nbd2 Nf6 6.Qb3 Qc8 7.g3**.

However a lot of those lines involve wide open tactical play, and you are looking for a quiet positional alternative. Therefore simply **3.Nc3** when Black can choose between several different openings.

- The main line Queen's Gambit Declined with **3...e6 4.Bg5 Be7 5.Nf3**.
- The Slav with **3...c6** can get tactical, so maybe play **4.e3 Bf5 5.Nf3 e6** when **6.Nh4** is popular, to get the advantage of two Bishops.
- The Queen's Gambit Accepted **3...dxc4 4.e3** or **4.e4** and you should easily regain the pawn.
- The Grünfeld Defence **3...g6** can also get quite tactical. **4.Bf4 Bg7 5.e3 O-O 6.Rc1** is one way to steer the game away in a quieter direction.